# Build matrix in sympy from list of submatrices

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I am using sympy (python module) and I am trying to declare a matrix from a list, but I need a specific way to declare it because the one I know are not suitable for my problem.

I have an array like this
`listm = [2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0]`
and I would like to declare a Matrix object such that each subset of 4 numbers (but in general I would like to  implement this for every n x n matrix) is a submatrix. I mean, the result must be like this:

```
[2,0,0,0]
[0,2,0,0]
[2,0,0,0]
[0,2,0,0]
```

If I declare in the usual way `mat = Matrix(4,4,listm)` I get instead

```
[2,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,0]
[2,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,0]
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The grouping in the "usual" way is obvious.  Your desired result isn't clear.

Comment: Take as example my list. The first 4 elements should be seen as a `Matrix(2,2,firstfourelements)`, the second four for another 2x2 matrix and so on. Then the four matrices obtained in this way are rearranged like a 4x4 matrix. I have also written my desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BlockMatrix can be instantiated with Matrix elements. So the trick in SymPy is to get your list (call it `L`) into a list of matrices that has the semantics you are describing. Assuming you want a 2x2 matrix of nxn elements, I would do something like this (showing for the case of `n = 3`:

```
>>> from sympy import BlockMatrix, Matrix
>>> from sympy.utilities.iterables import reshape
>>> n = 3
... L = [i for i in range(4*n**2)]
... m = [Matrix(n,n,i) for i in reshape(L, [n**2])]
... M = reshape(m, [2])
... Matrix(BlockMatrix(M))
... 
Matrix([
[ 0,  1,  2,  9, 10, 11],
[ 3,  4,  5, 12, 13, 14],
[ 6,  7,  8, 15, 16, 17],
[18, 19, 20, 27, 28, 29],
[21, 22, 23, 30, 31, 32],
[24, 25, 26, 33, 34, 35]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sufficiently familiar with `sympy` matrix code.  But with `numpy` it's relatively easy.

In an `isympy` session:

```
In [2]: listm = [2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0]
In [3]: import numpy as np
In [4]: arr = np.array(listm)
In [5]: arr
Out[5]: array([2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0])
In [6]: arr.reshape(4,4)
Out[6]: 
array([[2, 0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [7]: arr.reshape(2,2,2,2)
Out[7]: 
array([[[[2, 0],
         [0, 2]],

        [[0, 0],
         [0, 0]]],


       [[[2, 0],
         [0, 2]],

        [[0, 0],
         [0, 0]]]])
In [8]: arr.reshape(2,2,2,2).transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,4)
Out[8]: 
array([[2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0]])
```

And making a `sympy.Matrix` from that:

```
In [9]: Matrix(_)
Out[9]: 
⎡2  0  0  0⎤
⎢          ⎥
⎢0  2  0  0⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎢2  0  0  0⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎣0  2  0  0⎦
```